# Is there any way of resoring previous columns width size of all Execl sheets?

Tags: excel

As you can see on the following screenshots, the widths of columns changed for all my sheets. Now I'm unable to restore back to normal (regular) width size. I've also had custom widths, but now I need manually increase width for every column. Is there any setting to get back my previous width size?

[image: Screenshot of my Excel sheet]

[image: Another Screenshot from a different sheet in same file]

Comment: What error?  Looks like you just need to increase your column widths, but can't see an error.

Comment: Unable to restore Back to Normal(Regular)Width Size. Also had Custom Width Now I am Able to Increase Width But Every Column I have to do Manually.Is there any Setting to Get Back My Previous Width Size

Comment: I want to understand, how this happened

Comment: I would learn from the exprience and backup my changes regularly from now on.